# Correct way to reserve non-empty std::vector before push_back()

Tags: c++

I'm confused whether `N` in `vector::reserve(N)` is the number of elements that it expects to be added on top of the current vector size or the total space of the vector.

For example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> foo;

    foo.reserve(3);
    foo.push_back(1);
    foo.push_back(2);
    foo.push_back(3);

    foo.reserve(foo.size() + 2);// Should this be foo.reserve(2)?
    foo.push_back(4);
    foo.push_back(5);
}
```

Should the `foo.reserve(foo.size() + 2)` be just `foo.reserve(2)`?

Comment: You have it right http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/  although if you have to grow, it makes sense to multiply the size. You don't want a bunch of small allocations (which push_back can already do for you)

Comment: Also, note that calling `reserve` frequently (such as you're doing for every 2-3 pushes) can actually result in *worse* performance than just letting the container manage its own capacity.

Comment: Note that `vector` distinguishes *size* (number of elements) from *capacity* (allocation size / element size). `reserve` only increases the capacity

Comment: As a rule of thumb, only call `reserve` on an empty vector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Increase the capacity of the vector to a value that's greater or equal to new_cap. If new_cap is greater than the current capacity(), new storage is allocated, otherwise the method does nothing.

From the documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) it is clear that it is the total size.

Answer (score 3):

You should call `foo.reserve(foo.size() + 2)`, see [[vector.capacity]](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.capacity) (emphasis is mine):

> *Effects:* A directive that informs a vector of a planned change in size, so that it can manage the storage allocation accordingly.
>   **After `reserve()`, `capacity()` is greater or equal to the argument of `reserve` if reallocation happens;** and equal to the previous value of `capacity()` otherwise.
>   Reallocation happens at this point if and only if the current capacity is less than the argument of `reserve()`.
>   If an exception is thrown other than by the move constructor of a non-*Cpp17CopyInsertable* type, there are no effects.

Answer (score 2):

The argument needs to be `foo.size() + 2`.  To quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)

> [`reserve` will] increase the capacity of the vector to a value that's greater or equal to *new_cap*.